# Small subgroup attack when using a Schnorr group for DHKE

Tags: dsa, attack, group-theory

One uses a Schnorr group both for [Schnorr signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature) (or [DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm)), and for [Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange). They target 128-bit security, and choose prime $q$ that's 256-bit, prime $p=q\,r+1$ that's 3072-bit, and $g$ of order $q$ (e.g. $g=2^r\bmod p$). In DHKE, a participant chooses an ephemeral secret $x\in[1,q)$ uniformly at random, sends $X=g^x\bmod p$, receives $Y$ (only) checked to be in $(1,p)$, uses $Y^x\bmod p$ as the shared secret, which is used (only) as the input of a proper [Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). There's proper authentication on top of that using the signature scheme.

What's additional condition(s) on $p$ for DHKE to be safe from a [small subgroup attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_subgroup_confinement_attack)? If $p$ is chosen (non-maliciously) without this condition, what's the risk?

---

Update: I (now) realize it's not clear to me why a small subgroup attack would be to fear in authenticated DHKE modulo $p$.

Answer (score 1):

All $p$ would still be vulnerable to a small subgroup attack if presented with the $Y$ value $p-1$. In this case the adversary knows that the shared secret value is either $1$ or maybe $p-1$.

The adversary can try decryption using $\mathrm{KDF}(1)$ or $\mathrm{KDF}(p-1)$.

If a check $Y\neq p-1$ is added, there is still a risk when $r$ has a prime divisor $\ell$ that is small enough that an adversary can exhaust over $\ell$ possible keys. In this case by submitting $Y$ of order $\ell$, the adversary can limit the possible number of shared secrets  (and hence derived keys) to $\ell$ possibilities.

Unless $r$ is specifically chosen not to have any small prime factors (e.g. by choosing $r$ to be prime), then the risk is high as a *very* high proportion of $r$ have a small divisor.

Comment: So, are you suggesting the choice of `r` in such a way that it does not have small prime factors? One way to achieve this is by choosing `r` itself to be a prime number. This would make it much harder for an attacker to perform this type of attack, as the number of possible keys to exhaust would be prohibitively large.

Comment: I (now) realize that a small subgroup attack can happen only in a Man in the Middle scenario where $Y$ is doctored, and that the attack's (only?) objective is restricting the result of the KDF to a small set of values that the attacker can enumerate. But, as pointed in the answer, that can happen for $Y=p-1$ regardless of $p$, and it's is not (AFAIK) something specifically guarded against in DHKE (even ECDHKE). That's because "proper authentication" still prevents MitM. So now, it's not clear to me why (and if) a small subgroup attack is to be feared in the first place in DHKE modulo $p$.

Comment: @fgrieu-modelectiontime It's true that the attack outlined relies on the adversary influencing $Y$, but this is not necessarily limited to MitM. For example, if the adversary can change the choice of $g$ used by the other party (q.v. the CurveBall attack), then this would be an attack vector.

Comment: @fgrieu-modelectiontime What is the underlying authentication model of the question? For some protocol, the model allows for peers to be post-specified, e.,g.: SIGMA. Therefore, without additional mechanism like key confirmation signing itself is not enough to prevent authentication issues like identity misbinding. In such a model. The attacker can use the small subgroup attack i in this to "synchronize" session keys. Thereby forcing Alice and Bob into a session although, Bob thinks he is talking to the adversary and not Alice.

Comment: This [paper](https://antoine.delignat-lavaud.fr/doc/ndss15.pdf) by Bhargavan, Delignat-Lavaud and Pironti discusses these considerations for AKE based on DHKE.

Comment: @MarcIlunga: the Q originated from me making [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/111118/555) and realizing that I was not confident about if Schnorr groups (as in original Schnorr signature and DSA) are OK for DHKE, and under what condition, with respect to small subgroup attack. I do not have a precise application in mind, or model for the authentication on top of DHKE, except that it's based on signature of some challenge. I realize it may matter if that challenge involves $Y$, or some output of the KDF, and more generally the protocol matters.